# Создание исполняемого файла .exe из Java программы

Tags: java, javafx, swing, exe

Есть ли способ сделать из Java swing-приложения (или в крайнем случае Java FX) исполняемый файл .exe?
И, если можно, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

- [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)
- [JexePack](http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html)
- [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже недавно искал способ и вот, нашёл: [JEXE Creator](http://www.ucware.com/jexec/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, сделать из bat - exe, или на С++ написать консольную команду на загрузку готовой библиотеки.

Comment: Очень интересно. И как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Слышал несколько лет назад про GCJ, но он был сырой. Может сейчас что-то изменилось?

Comment: Он всё ещё сырой и работает такой код всё равно медленно..