# Возможно ли создать аналог "Open With" на Java?

Tags: java, desktop

В Windows есть функциональность "Open With"

[image]

Мне интересно, можно ли создать аналог "Open With" на Java? Допустим, у нам задан файл.

- Нужно получить список "рекомендованных" программ для открытия файла.
- Нужно оставить возможность пользователю выбрать произвольную программу.
- Иначе предложить пользователю скачать программу через интернет.
- Попытаться открыть файл (так, как указал пользователь).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроссплатформенно есть/был проект [JDIC](http://java.net/projects/jdic/) - но последний коммит у них там был год назад и страница с загрузками пуста.

Для вызова непосредственно под Windows можно воспользоваться функцией из `shell32.dll`, вызвав ее из командной строки или через `JNI`. В простейшем случае:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32.exe shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL c:\\file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Для `Windows` вы можете создать из `Java`-программы `exe`-шник. Так пользователям будет намного проще. В интернете полно программ, делающих из `Java`-программы `exe`-шники. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/13302/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-exe-%D0%B8%D0%B7-java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B) уже было обсуждение.

Comment: Мне не надо создавать exe-шник.

Comment: Тогда думается мне, что это можно установить в настройках винды. Ведь это же ОНА решает, как открывать какие-либо типы файлов. И еще идея, в какую сторону можно покапать: При установке какой-либо программы, установочник как-то ставит для `Windows` правило, с помощью какой программы открывать определенное разрешение файлов.

Comment: Антон, вы, наверно, не так поняли вопрос. Автор хочет аналогичное окно открыть у себя в Java-программе. @Зохан, так?

Comment: Именно так. В своей программе я работаю с файлами.

Answer (score 0):

сам только недавно начал изучать это, приведенный ниже код работает:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
// Note: source for ExampleFileFilter can be found in FileChooserDemo,
// under the demo/jfc directory in the Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition.
ExampleFileFilter filter = new ExampleFileFilter();
filter.addExtension("jpg");
filter.addExtension("gif");
filter.setDescription("JPG & GIF Images");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
```

извини, не могу разжевать что за что отвечает, так как еще не знаю, но думаю тут найдутся ребята которые смогут.

Comment: @arachnoden, это совсем не то. Посмотрите на ответ пользователя @yozh.

Answer (score 0):

это не совсем то что вам нужно, но возможно будет полезным:

Создаем файлик Test.java с вот таким содержимым:

`public class Test
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}`

1) создаем привязку .java файла к какой-то программе напр. eclipse
1.1) для этого в проводнике выбираем открыть с помощью... 
1.2) указываем полный путь до программы и ставим галочку запомнить (чтоб он всегда открывался этой программой)

2.1) запускаем regedit
2.2) открываем ветку `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.java`
2.3) смотрим значение ключа (Default), у меня это 'java_auto_file'
2.4) ищем в этой же ветке 'java_auto_file', у меня этот ключ имеет примерно следующее содержимое

```
java_auto_file-->shell-->open-->command:
(Default)="D:\programming\java\eclipse12\eclipse.exe" "%1"
```

3) Создаем свою строчку в контекстном меню
3.1) Создаем еще одну ветку с тем же содержимым:

`java_auto_file-->shell-->Compile-->command  
(Default)="D:\programming\java\eclipse12\eclipse.exe" "%1"`

3.2) Заменяем путь к программе на путь к java компилятору:

`(Default)="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javac.exe" "%1"`

4) компилируем класс
4.1) в проводнике из контекстного меню нашего файла выбираем пункт "compile" (тот который мы добавили) 
4.2) существующий пункт open можно удалить при желании

аналогично для .class файла действием по умолчанию можно сделать его запуск